# arm cortex a9 cross compiling strange floating point behaviour

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to port a larger application from x86 to arm cortex a9, but I'm getting strange segmentation faults with floating point functions like modf when cross compiling the application, other libc++ functions just seem to handle floats wrong, but don't crash(see below).

So I tried this small test programm, which can trigger the error too.
The output of the test programm(see below) should demonstrate my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double x = 80;
    double y = 0;
    std::cout << x << "\t" << y << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled on arm cortex a9:

```
@tegra$ g++ -Wall test.cpp -o test_nativ
@tegra$ ./test_nativ 
80      0
```

cross compiled

```
@x86$ arm-cortex_a9-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.cpp  -o test_cc
@tegra$ ./test_cc
0       1.47895e-309
```

cross compiled with '-static' linker option.

```
@x86$ arm-cortex_a9-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static test.cpp  -o test_cc_static
@tegra$ ./test_cc_static 
80      0
```

.

```
@x86$ arm-cortex_a9-linux-gnueabi-objdump -S test_cc
see: http://pastebin.com/3kqHHLgQ

@tegra$ objdump -S test_nativ
see: http://pastebin.com/zK35KL4X
```

.

To answer some of the comments below:
- Cross compiler is setup for little endian, as is the native compiler on the tegra machine.
- I don't believe its a memory alignment issue, had my share of these while porting to arm and these should send SIGBUS to application or log to syslog, see documentation for /proc/cpu/alignment.

My current workaround is to copy over the crosscompiled toolchain and use it with LD_LIBRARY_PATH ... not nice, but good enough for the time being.

Edit:
Thank you for your Answers.
In the meantime I found out that the linux distribution on the tegra device was compiled with '-mfloat-abi=softfp' though the documentation stated, that a toolchain compiled with '-mfloat-abi=hard' is required.

Changing the toolchain brought the success.

It seems that the difference between hard and softfp can be seen using 'readelf -A' on any system binary:
If the Output contains the line: 'Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers' it is compiled with '-mfloat-abi=hard'. If this line is missing the binary is most likely compiled with '-mfloat-abi=softfp'.

The line 'Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP' does not indicate the compilerflag '-mfloat-abi=hard'.

Comment: adding -v to switches will also show implicit flags

Comment: have you read this? http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Floating-Point.html

Comment: can you run and post the results for "arm-cortex_a9-linux-gnueabi-objdump -S test_*"

Comment: Does the version of libstdc++ used by the cross-toolchain in fact match the one used on the target? Is the program large enough that trying to sort out cross-compilation issues won't outweigh the time it would take to simply build natively?

Comment: No, tegra uses:
gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

and crosscompiler uses: 
gcc version 4.5.3 (crosstool-NG 1.16.0)

Comment: second objdump is missing after text. one code is in thumb other one is in arm mode. try to compile them -marm -O2 to get rid of the crowdness. I'm just wondering the libraries you are using like @unixsmurf. It might also be much cleaner if you can come up with a simpler function failing in a similar way like double t(double d) {return d/80;}

Comment: I have to ask if you (or your compiler) are making an assumption about endianness of floats since the ARM processor supports big- and little-endian modes, depending on the OS.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave, even an endianness problem wouldn't change `0` to `1.47895e-309`.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, it can. there can be all sorts of wacky representations, including mixed-endianness inside the FPU, or cases where the FPU doesn't accept software-swapped endianness, or bad software emulation. vendors can also use their own FPU designs. the OP didn't specify which core specifically was being used, with which FP unit, on which OS.

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave but `0` is special, it's represented by all zero bits. There's no way to rearrange it that doesn't result in a `0`. I'm thinking it's more likely to be an ABI mismatch.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, there is -0. The OP should really set it to 0F. And part of me wonders if it could be a memory alignment issue, but not enough to go through the assembly output.

Comment: Both pastebin links seems to have same content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the assembly output, we can see a discrepancy in the two files.

In `test_nativ`:

```
86ec:       4602            mov     r2, r0
86ee:       460b            mov     r3, r1
86f0:       f241 0044       movw    r0, #4164       ; 0x1044
86f4:       f2c0 0001       movt    r0, #1
86f8:       f7ff ef5c       blx     85b4 <_init+0x20>
```

This is passing a `double` in `r2:r3`, and `std::cout` in `r0`.

In `test_cc`:

```
86d8:       e28f3068        add     r3, pc, #104    ; 0x68
86dc:       e1c320d0        ldrd    r2, [r3]
86e0:       e14b21f4        strd    r2, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
86e4:       e3010040        movw    r0, #4160       ; 0x1040
86e8:       e3400001        movt    r0, #1
86ec:       ed1b0b03        vldr    d0, [fp, #-12]
86f0:       ebffffa5        bl      858c <_init+0x20>
```

This passes a `double` in `d0` (a VFP register), and `std::cout` in `r0`. Observe here that `r2:r3` is loaded (by `ldrd`) with the floating point value that is printed out second, i.e. 0.0. Because the dynamically-linked `ostream::operator<<(double val)` expects its argument in `r2:r3`, 0 is printed out first.

I can explain the second weird-looking float too. Here's where the second float is printed:

```
8708:       e1a03000        mov     r3, r0
870c:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
8710:       ed1b0b05        vldr    d0, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
8714:       ebffff9c        bl      858c <_init+0x20>
```

See that `r3` is set to `r0`, the address of `cout`. From above, `r0 = 0x011040`. Thus, the register pair `r2:r3` becomes 0x0001104000000000, which decodes to 1.478946186471156e-309 as a double.

So the problem is that your desktop GCC's libraries uses VFP/NEON instructions, which are not used by the on-device dynamic libraries. If you use `-static`, you get the VFP/NEON libraries, and everything works again.

My suggestion would just be to figure out why the device and compiler libraries differ, and get that sorted out.

Comment: cool! I think OP can verify this with arm-cortex_a9-linux-gnueabi-g++ test.cpp -mfloat-abi=softfp -o test_cc (it looks like cross compiled tool chain has hard set by default)

Answer (score 0):

My **guess**: Without proper switches indicating vfp hardware support, the compiler will use software libraries to do floating point math on arm. If you compile with static linking, these libraries will get included into binary -- result: it works. If you use normal (dynamic) linking mode the libraries do not get included -- result: it does not work for some reason. The libraries on your tegra system are somehow incompatibile (probably due to calling convention) with what your crosscompiler is producing.