# Android NDK: libc++ support for hard-float

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am running into problems when compiling a small Java program that uses several custom c++ libraries. All the libraries are targeting armeabi-v7a and are compiled with hard-float support (mfloat-abi=hard
-mfpu=neon -mhard-float -D_NDK_MATH_NO_SOFTFP=1). I have couple of other cpp files that are part of the Java/Android project; those are also compiled with the above settings and I link against libm_hard.a (instead of libm.a)

When I run the program, I am getting strange behavior with floats from the cpp files (not custom libraries), similar to [arm cortex a9 cross compiling strange floating point behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800525/arm-cortex-a9-cross-compiling-strange-floating-point-behaviour?rq=1). Legitimate float values (in the code, checked via the debugger) are printed on stdout or fstream as extremely small values (e.g. 1.47895e-309).

```
  std::ofstream os;
  os.open(filename, std::ios::out);

  double x = 0.34343;
  double y = log(0.1);

  os << x << "\t" << y << endl;

  os.close();
```

It seems like this happens because libc++ library is not compiled for hard-float; I tried both static and shared version of libc++, and I get the same behavior. I also checked them via readelf and it appears that they are not compiled for hard-float (no mention of VPF registers). I was not able to find a version of libc++ (static nor shared) that's compiled for hard-float in the NDK.

- Android SDK: 21 (tried with 23 as well)
- NDK: 14.1.3816874
- Android Studio: 2.3.1

I can't (easily) change the upstream libraries from hard-float to softfp; some are focused on heavy matrix processing and optimized for hard-float. And, from what I understand, I cannot mix softfp and hard...

Beyond recompiling libc++ for hard-float, do I have any other options? (I understand a while back Google dropped support for hard abi, which must have had corresponding libc++ library)

EDIT: added example code

Comment: Post the code you're using to output your float values. If it is the `libc++` library that's the problem, there might be a way to convert the `float` values to a string that can be output.  Maybe C-style `printf()` or similar would work, also.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that, although I think it may be the same issue just deferring to libc instead of libc++. Also, there may be other places (some which I don't have control over) in 3rd party libraries where libc++ dependencies that would cause the issue would occur.

Comment: @AndrewHenle your suggestion worked (at least for dealing with text io and floats), thanks again. I am  still curious of other people experience linking with libc++ compiled with hard-float flag(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hard float ABI support was removed from the NDK in r12: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/HardFloatAbi.md

Stop using libm_hard and you should be fine (not removing this was an oversight that is fixed in r15, sorry for the confusion!).

It's really important to note that the non-hard-float-ABI still uses floating point instructions. The only difference is the function argument passing ABI.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure I understand your suggestion: I should not link with libm_hard and should also remove all the compiler flags related to hard-float when compiling my app, correct? When I do that I start running into issues (NaN values for some doubles) with one of the 3rd party libraries which was compiled with hard-float support. I can try to look more into why this is happening, but wanted to make sure that I understand what you are suggesting, i.e. that I should still be able to link against libs built with hard-float flags?

Comment: The hard-float library you're depending on should annotate its headers with `__attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))` if their functions use the hard-float calling convention. You don't need to remove the `-mfpu=neon` flag, just the `-mfloat-abi=hard` and `-mhard-float` (which are redundant, btw).